# Regex match without outer parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I having string: `(%new_town_(building_house)%)`
My regex is:

```cs
_RegexOpt = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace |
            RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled;

Regex reSet = new Regex(@"(?<!\\) \( (?<set> ([^\)]|\\\))+?) (?<!\\) \)", _RegexOpt);
```

But it match group `'set'` with: `(%new_town_(building_house`
Lost: `)%`

How gets group `'set'` without outer parenthesis: `%new_town_(building_house)%`

Input string have be more inner parentheses.
And input string can be without '%', Like this:(new_town_((building)*house)%), (new_town*((building)*house)), (%new_town*((building)_house))

Comment: Don't you just want "whatever is in between `(%` and `%)`", matched non-greedy? E.g. `\(%.*?%\)`?

Comment: What is the syntax of the input strings? Can there be more inner parentheses? Without the exact pattern requirements even `\((?<set>%[^%]*%)\)`  can work.

Comment: >Can there be more inner parentheses? - Yes

Comment: We need to know more on the template syntax, as I'm not sure that the other examples of "*Find a string between 2 known values*" are sufficient. Try out something like this, where I took in consideration strings that could contain `%)` and cause trouble: https://regex101.com/r/iYRDna/1

Comment: >Can there be more inner parentheses? - Yes. And input string can be without <code>'%'</code>, Like this: <code>(new_town_((building)_house)%),  (new_town_((building)_house)),  (%new_town_((building)_house))</code>

Comment: Match group 'set' must be without without outer parenthesis, but the % character must be there if it is in the input string